# How do I use drupal_mail() without the $to value?

Tags: 7, emails

I'm trying to send same email to several users at once. They should not see each other's email addresses, so I add them as `Bcc` in the header.

However, the problem is that Drupal seems to require the `$to` parameter passed to `drupal_mail()` function. I tried passing both `NULL` and an empty string but without success. System would return the `Unable to send e-mail.` message.

I don't want to use some random email address instead and I want to avoid new modules.

How can I send an email just with BCC recipients?

Comment: You can't - emails require at least one recipient, that's not a Drupal thing. Just send it to `variable_get('site_mail')`, that's the most oft-used solution I've seen

Comment: Could also loop through your list of addresses and send them one by one.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Clive. I guess I'll have to send them through as queue batch and see how other modules solved this problem. Please add your comment as a separate answer so I can accept it.

Comment: The way I did it was: ask admins to configure "resend" address on the mail server. Update recipient list daily via XML. Yes, hard part was on their side. Then I was just sending mail to that address and mailserver was re-sending it where needed. So it's like @Beebee solution, only with "loop" moved elsewhere ;)

Comment: @Mołot thanks for the comment; in this particular case the recipients are determined dynamically (values are from the DB) so it's not possible to update the list manually.

Comment: @Beebee do you know if this would work without issues if I'm trying to send ~50 emails at once?

Comment: @Ivanhoe123 I know. Kinda. I know that only way to really know is to test. It depends on your server's performance. And performance of it's network. And exact configuration. And the fact if you are using mailserver or sending directly. If via mailserver, then it depends on it's performance too. If directly, performance of recipient's servers may be (or not) a problem. Too many factors to really know. But with good use of batch api you should be reasonably safe.

Comment: Thanks again. I believe the server side won't be a problem; it's a dedicated server without any limits for sending emails. I guess I'll have to experiment with Queue API now, as this is happening in the background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this by putting the string `'undisclosed-recipients:;'` (notice the colon and semicolon at the end) is the `$to` parameter you pass to the `drupal_mail` function. E.g.:

```
drupal_mail('mymodule', 'send', 'undisclosed-recipients:;', $language, $params);
```

You can now add the list of bcc-recipients to the header.

Comment: Didn't know for this approach, thanks a lot! Do you know if it will generate some error logs in the background or this is an accepted way of leaving recipient empty?

Comment: This is the accepted way of leaving the recipient empty. It is used in examples in RFC 2822.

Comment: Thanks again for lightning fast response :) I will check this  and post back/mark the question as the answer.

Comment: Thanks once again, and sorry it took me so long - I simply forgot about it. This worked perfectly.